# Overloading fstream << operator to save "any" kind of data

Tags: c++, save, operator-overloading, ostream

I have created a *Test class* that has a public variable *double x*. I have overloaded the *ostream <<* operater to be able to print out the variable *x*. I have also written an external *save(filename, object)* function that would save the content of the object in a particular way. I would like to use the << operator to save the content of *x* into a file. 
Header file (TestH.hpp) looks like this:

```
#ifndef TESTH_HPP_
#define TESTH_HPP_

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>


class Test {
public:
    double x;
friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, Test& p);
inline Test();
inline virtual ~Test();
};

inline std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, Test& p);
template <class V>
inline void save(const std::string& pname, const V& data);

#endif /* TESTH_HPP_ */
```

This is the file for defining the functions (TestC.cpp):

```
#ifndef TESTC_CPP_
#define TESTC_CPP_

#include "TestH.hpp"

Test::Test() {
    x=10;
}

Test::~Test() {}

std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, Test& p) {
 // Output to screen
    os << "Test:\t";
    os << p.x;
    return os;
}

template <class V>
void save(const std::string& pname, const V& data) {
    std::ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open(pname.c_str());
    myfile << data;
    myfile.close();
    std::cout << "====== File is saved! ======\nPathname: " << pname << std::endl;
}

#endif /* TESTC_CPP_ */
```

And finally here is the code to test the save function (Test.cpp):

```
#include <iostream>
#include "TestC.cpp"

int main () {
    std::string fn = "test.txt";
    int i=1;
    Test a;

//  std::cout << a;
    save(fn,a);
    return 0;
}
```

I get a really long list of errors, but basically it sais that in the TestC.cpp code the compiler cannot do the *myfile << data;* command:

```
In file included from ../Test.cpp:3:0:
../TestC.cpp:33:9: note:   ‘const Test’ is not derived from ‘const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>’
  myfile << data;
```

Could you please help me resolving this issue. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are streaming `Test` by non-const reference:

```
friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, Test& p);
```

You want to stream it by const reference:

```
friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Test& p);
                                                    ^^^^^^
```

The error comes from the fact that when you call it from `save()`, you are passing in a const reference:

```
template <class V>
void save(const std::string& pname, const V& data) {
    ...
    myfile << data; // <== data is const Test&
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I really missed that my definitions were inconsistante. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You get the error because you are trying to save a const object and you have overloaded the operator for non const case.

Turn

```
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, Test& p) {
```

into

```
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Test& p) {
```